# Use only xhr polling on socket.io

Tags: socket.io

I was using only xhr-polling on socket.io v0.9 but now in 1.0 I couldn't find this option.You know antiviruse bans the websocket so I want to use xhr-polling.How can I achive this ?

Comment: Why would anti-virus ban webSocket?  That makes no sense to me.  From the anti-virus program's point of view, it's just a long running outbound HTTP connection which it allows already and it affords no more risk than any HTTP connection.  I could see how maybe a personal firewall might be picky about the long running webSocket (though not usually an issue since it's an outbound HTTP connection).

Comment: Firstly,I was running it on websocket and some users says to me "I can't send a message" then I switched to xhr polling and everything is fine now.

Comment: Looking at the docs for [EngineIO](https://github.com/Automattic/engine.io), which is the underlying transport layer abstraction for socket.io 1.0, it looks like this is abstracted away so that your socket.io code will look like it's using WebSockets even if it's really xhr-polling.

Comment: The socket.io documentation is not very clear about how to do this (nor do I remember exactly where I saw it), but there is an option somewhere that allows you to list which transports the socket.io engine is allowed to use.  You should be able to specify only xhr-polling, but you shouldn't have to do that.  It should be possible to use webSockets for the majority of users that support it and let the engine fall back to xhr-polling when webSockets aren't supported.  webSockets are way, way more efficient than xhr-polling.

Answer (score 4):

Several examples on how to set the allowed socket.io transports here: https://github.com/Automattic/socket.io/wiki/configuring-socket.io

Here are some of the:

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(80);

io.configure('production', function(){
  io.enable('browser client etag');
  io.set('log level', 1);

  io.set('transports', [
    'websocket'
  , 'flashsocket'
  , 'htmlfile'
  , 'xhr-polling'
  , 'jsonp-polling'
  ]);
});

io.configure('development', function(){
  io.set('transports', ['websocket']);
});
```

or just this:

```
// enable all transports (optional if you want flashsocket support, please note that some hosting
// providers do not allow you to create servers that listen on a port different than 80 or their
// default port)
io.set('transports', [
  'xhr-polling'
]);
```

Or, options can be set when the server is initialized:

```
var socket = require('socket.io').listen(80, {
  // options can go here
  transports: ['xhr-polling']
});
```

Comment: Pretty sure this is no longer valid with socket.io 1.0